# Show number of answers with questions in "Related" pane instead of the vote count? Or even both?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

*(This is mainly about unix.SE, but it might be a general thing to consider as well.)*

I'm wondering whether it would be much better to have the *number of answers* shown in the "Related" pane.
The "0" always confuses the heck out of me, because I always keep thinking that this question has no answers yet (and might just be still in need of *my* contribution!) But once I click into there, I can see lots of answers, because I've been fooled again: the "0" indicates in fact that there are 0 *votes* (which does not necessarily imply that it's a low-quality question, mind you!)

Another advantage of this would be that questions previously overlooked will attract user attention again because it shows that this question is still wanting an answer. The current way of having to check out every related question by hand for its number of answers is, to put it mildly, cumbersome.